# VSCode - Getting 'Unable to resolve nonexisting file' error after build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm building a C++ project in VSCode, and configured a build a task for compiling the project.

The compilation errors are parsed into the "Problems" view, but when clicking a problem I get an error: "Unable to resolve nonexisting file", and the file containing the problem isn't opened.

How do i make VSCode to open the file with the errors?

This is my tasks.json file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The file location parsing depends on whether your building command produces relative or absolute paths for the compilation errors, and this requires a correct configuration of the `problemMatcher` field.

In case your compiler produces absolute paths, the configuration is:

```
    "problemMatcher": {
            "base": "$gcc",
            "fileLocation": "absolute"
    },
```

In case your compiler produces relative paths, the configuration is:

```
    "problemMatcher": {
            "base": "$gcc",
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "<path>"]
    },
```

Where `<path>` is the path where the files in the error messages are relative to

In case your compiler produces both, you can configure the `problemMatcher` with `autoDetect`